# Was -ю ending in instrumental mandatory in Pushkin's times?

Tags: падежи, история-языка, окончания

Was -ю ending in instrumental mandatory or overwhelming in Pushkin's times?

Comment: Нет, вероятно. Навскидку из собственно Пушкина: _В крови горит огонь желанья, /
Душа **тобой** уязвлена, /
Лобзай меня: твои лобзанья /
Мне слаще мирра и вина._

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov С другой стороны Пушкин сделал разговорный язык литературным. Вопрос в том о какой норме вопрос - о Пушкинской, или о принятой "до Пушкина" и актуальной в то время.

Comment: @Artemix Из допушкинского высокого стиля: _„Народ наш, тронутый заслугой толь великой, / Поставил над собой спасителя владыкой“_ — Яков Княжнин.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Т.е. ответ "нет".

Comment: @Artemix Вероятно. Однако, поэзия вообще не очень показательна в таких вопросах, ибо допускает многие вольности, но здесь хороша тем, что не требует обращения к оригиналам xıx века — в прозе этот момент могли и осовременить при приведении к новой правописной норме.

Answer (score 5):

В такой формулировке вопрос напрашивается на односложный ответ. Можно за минуту найти с десяток примеров окончания *-ой* из произведений уважаемых авторов, чего вполне достаточно, чтобы ответить: «нет, не была обязательна».

И до Пушкина:

> Народ наш, тронутый *заслугой* толь *великой*, /
>   Поставил над *собой* спасителя *владыкой* 
>   [Яков Княжнин].

И во времена Пушкина:

> *Злой тоской* удручена, /
>   К Муравью ползет она: /
>   «Не оставь меня, кум милый! /
>   Дай ты мне собраться с *силой*...
>   [И. А. Крылов]

И у самого Пушкина:

> В крови горит огонь желанья, /
>   Душа *тобой* уязвлена, /
>   Лобзай меня: твои лобзанья /
>   Мне слаще мирра и вина

Какие появились основания полагать, что окончание *-ой* было недопустимо, не знаю. Да, преобладало, по всей видимости, *-ою*. Причем, если взглянуть на частоту по Гугловскому корпусу трех самых частых слов русского языка, допускающих вариацию *-ой* / *-ою* в творительном падеже — местоимений: *мной*, *тобой*, *собой*,

[image]

то, видно, что по крайней мере в этих словах преобладало оно аж до первой половины xx века. В более редких словах — раньше.

Выше я приводил стихотворные примеры, но можно возразить, что поэзия не очень показательна в таких вопросах, ибо допускает многие вольности, хотя здесь и хороша тем, что не требует обращения к оригиналам xıx века — в прозе этот момент могли и осовременить при приведении к новой правописной норме.

Однако, часто и к оригиналам обратиться не сложно. К примеру, издание «Сочинений» Пушкина, подготовленное Жуковским, у Гугля есть целиком и даже кое-как распознанное. Так вот, например, в «Истории Пугачева», форма *собою* встречается 23 раза, а *собой* — 6. Причем, будто бы просто для разнообразия:

> Сначала оба племени враждовали *между собою*, но въ послѣдствіи времени вошли въ дружелюбныя сношенія: казаки стали получать женъ изъ Татарскихъ улусовъ. Сохранилось поэтическое преданіе: казаки, страстные къ холостой жизни положили *между собой* убивать приживаемыхъ дѣтей, а женъ бросать при выстуиленіи въ новый походъ.

Что касается наставлений по грамматике русского языка, то их, наисколько мне известно, в первой половине xıx века было два: Греча и Востокова. В Сети доступны только относительно поздние издания, и они характеризуют обсуждаемый феномен сходным образом:

> Окончаніе *ою* и *ею*, въ творительномъ падежѣ ед. числа женскаго рода, иногда сокращается; напримѣръ: *черной шубой*, *свѣжей ягодой* и т. п.

— Н. И. Гречъ — Начальныя правила русской грамматики — СПб, 1842 — С. 27

> Также творительный падежъ единств. числа женскаго рода сокращается въ мѣстоименияхъ, какъ въ существительныхъ и прилагательныхъ именахъ, на *ей*, *ой*; напр. *моей*, вм. *моею*.

— А. Х. Востоковъ — Сокращенная русская грамматика — М, 1845 — Ч. I. Гл. III. § 46